# Find the line `(t) through (3, 1, −2) that intersects and is perpendicular to the line s(t) = (−1 + t, −2 + t, −1 + t).

Tags: geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, inner-products

I'm drawing a blank as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A(3,1,-2)$ and $B(-1+t,-2+t,-1+t)$.

Thus, $$\vec{AB}(-4+t,-3+t,1+t)$$ and since we need $AB\perp(1,1,1),$ we obtain
$$-4+t-3+t+1+t=0,$$
which gives $t=2$, 
$$\vec{AB}(-2,-1,3)$$ and we got the answer:
$$(3-2s,1-s,-2+3s).$$

Comment: What is the significance of (1,1,1) or is that just used to find the perpendicular line?

Comment: @Geoffrey Zhen $s(t)=(-1,-2,-1)+t(1,1,1)$. It gives that the vector  $(1,1,1)$ is parallel to the given line. We need that $AB$ will be perpendicular to the given line. Thus, $AB\perp(1,1,1)$.